# Currency Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please find the below sample data. There are 2 tables Transaction and Exchange rate. If i need to convert the transactions table to USD then below is the query which i have tried but it doesnt give the required output.

**Transaction**

| Currency | Local_Price |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 1000 |
| GBP | 100 |
| EUR | 10 |
| USD | 100 |

**ExchangeRate**

| From_Currency | To_Currency | Exchange_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USD | GBP | 0.9 |
| EUR | USD | 1.1 |
| GBP | USD | 1.3 |

**Expected Output**

| Currency | Local_Price | In_USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 1000 | 1000 |
| GBP | 100 | 130 |
| EUR | 10 | 11 |
| USD | 100 | 100 |

**Query**
Select Currency,Local_price, Local_Price*Exchange_Rate  as In_USD
from Transaction T
left join ExchangeRate ER on T.Currency=ER.From_Currency and To_Currency='USD'

I do not have data from USD to USD or EUR to EUR or GBP to GBP in my exchange rate table.

Please help me with the query for required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
Select Currency,Local_price,
       ( Local_Price * coalesce(Exchange_Rate, 1) ) as In_USD
from Transaction T left join
     ExchangeRate ER
     on T.Currency = ER.From_Currency and To_Currency = 'USD';
```

Comment: How do i get all three currency conversions in one table. Similar to USD lets say GBP and EUR. GBP, EUR and USD in one table against local currency

Comment: @user2293950 . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: Added new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328154/multiple-currency-conversions-in-single-query